# Elegant way to get index of filter or first with RX Java

Tags: java, filter, rx-java

I'm just practicing RX Java and wanted to get the position in an array for items which match a filter.  I can't see any obvious way to do it. I was looking at maybe zipping a range and iterable observable or something but it was quickly getting way more verbose and complicated than for loops.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There used to be `mapWithIndex` and `zipWithIndex` operators in RxJava, but they were removed, see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rxjava/y0KMO7ci0QE) why.

So you have to write some library boilerplate once:

```
class Indexed<T> {
    final int index;
    final T value;
    public Indexed(T value, int index) {
        this.index = index;
        this.value = value;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return index + ") " + value;
    }
}

Iterable<Integer> naturals = IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1)::iterator;
```

But then, you can get it reasonably concise:

```
Observable<String> obs = Observable.just("zero", "one", "two", "three");
obs.zipWith(naturals, (s, i) -> new Indexed<String>(s, i))
   .filter(e -> e.value.length() > 4)
   .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Comment: You can use `Observable.range(0, list.size())` instead of `naturals` if you don't have access to java 8 streams.

Comment: The accepted answer can be simplified by relying on Map.SimpleEntry:

`flow.zipWith(LongStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1)::iterator, SimpleEntry::new)`

Answer (score 4):

There is not one correct way to do this. Samuel's answer can be one.
It also depends the bigger picture on what is you array and how you need to handle the results in the subscriber.

Here is a (java7) example where the Observer emits a `ArrayList<String>`:

```
strings.map(new Func1<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public ArrayList<Integer> call(ArrayList<String> strings) {
                ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
                for(String string: strings){
                    if(statement){
                        list.add(strings.indexOf(string));
                    }
                }
                return list;
            }
        }).subscribe(new Action1<ArrayList<Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public void call(ArrayList<Integer> integers) {
                doSomethingWithThePositions(integers);
            }
        });
```

And here is an example where the Observer emits a `String` per time from your ArrayList:

```
final ArrayList<String> strings1 = new ArrayList<>();
Observable.from(strings1)
        .filter(new Func1<String, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call(String s) {
                return !s.isEmpty();
            }
        })
        .subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
            @Override
            public void call(String s) {
                int i = strings1.indexOf(s);
                doSomethingWithThePosition(i);
            }
        });
```

Comment: yeah that second example isn't bad, first one was exactly was I was trying to avoid, also the custom tuple class sam mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

I like Samuel's answer. I've written a Transformer implementation of his stuff which is Java 6/7 compliant and uses a Long index (I have long streams to deal with!).

You call it like this:

```
Observable.just("a", "b").compose(MapWithIndex.<String>instance());
```

Here's the class (source and unit tests [here](https://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava-extras)):

```
package com.github.davidmoten.util;

import java.util.Iterator;

import rx.Observable;
import rx.Observable.Transformer;
import rx.functions.Func2;

import com.github.davidmoten.util.MapWithIndex.Indexed;

public final class MapWithIndex<T> implements Transformer<T, Indexed<T>> {

    private static class Holder {
        static final MapWithIndex<?> INSTANCE = new MapWithIndex<Object>();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> MapWithIndex<T> instance() {
        return (MapWithIndex<T>) Holder.INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<Indexed<T>> call(Observable<T> source) {

        return source.zipWith(NaturalNumbers.instance(), new Func2<T, Long, Indexed<T>>() {

            @Override
            public Indexed<T> call(T t, Long n) {
                return new Indexed<T>(t, n);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class Indexed<T> {
        private final long index;
        private final T value;

        public Indexed(T value, long index) {
            this.index = index;
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return index + "->" + value;
        }

        public long index() {
            return index;
        }

        public T value() {
            return value;
        }

    }

    private static final class NaturalNumbers implements Iterable<Long> {

        private static class Holder {
            static final NaturalNumbers INSTANCE = new NaturalNumbers();
        }

        static NaturalNumbers instance() {
            return Holder.INSTANCE;
        }

        @Override
        public Iterator<Long> iterator() {
            return new Iterator<Long>() {

                private long n = 0;

                @Override
                public boolean hasNext() {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public Long next() {
                    return n++;
                }

                @Override
                public void remove() {
                    throw new RuntimeException("not supported");
                }
            };
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Cool thanks for sharing I stared your git project for future reference could come in handy some day!

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for the index of the first element which meet one condition, then you can simply do this

```kotlin
var index = -1
stream$
  .doOnNext{ index++}
  .any { it % 2 == 0 } // your condition
  .subscribe { print("index = $index") }
```