# How to get index / position of list in onnext from Observable.fromIterable Rxjava?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm trying to loop a list but i'm not getting the index of current item.

```
Observable.fromIterable(yourList).observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(
                { item -> {        }},
                {_ ->{}},
                {->{}}
```

Is there any way to get index just like

```
yourList.forEachIndexed{ index, item -> }
```

I already know that

```
class Indexed {
int index;
String element;

Indexed(int index, String element) {
    this.index = index;
    this.element = element;
    }
}
```

this can be used as a solution. But i don't like this kind of approach. I want to know whether Rxjava itself has something for it.

Comment: @Gustavo  scenario which i required and the solution which i had accepted is entirely different from that question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `Iterable.withIndex()` like this:

```
Observable.fromIterable(yourList.withIndex())
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe(
        { (index, item) -> {} },
        { _ -> {} },
        { -> {} }
    )
```

Comment: I was not aware of this method `withIndex()`, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Using Java you can solve that by creating an indexed element and map all your list items to be indexed items. If you have `String` list then you can do something like this:

```
class Indexed {
    int index;
    String element;

    Indexed(int index, String element) {
        this.index = index;
        this.element = element;
    }
}
```

Then use

```
List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");

Observable.fromIterable(stringList)
        .map(s -> new Indexed(stringList.indexOf(s), s))
        .subscribe(indexed -> {
            Log.i("TAG", "index: " + indexed.index + ", element: " + indexed.element);
        });
```

**EDIT:**

Just found a more generic way to [implement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30143591/elegant-way-to-get-index-of-filter-or-first-with-rx-java) this.